# Trigger - Access a user's Missed Call log

Tags: android, trigger.io

How can I access a user's call log while developing with Trigger.io? Specifically, I want some  code to be executed when a missed call happens. Can someone show me how to do any of the above two things using Trigger.io?

Comment: Anyone else think this pushes privacy boundaries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We don't currently have any plans to support this: no official API is available on iOS, and we wouldn't jeopardise the success of other Trigger.io users apps by including code which is frowned upon by Apple.

Comment: OK, I understand that. Then is there any way to access and use Listeners and Permissions besides what's there in the API for Android only?

Comment: Not yet, but we're just polishing v0 of a plugins system which will let you add your own native functionality where the normal modules aren't enough.

Answer (score 0):

Accessing a user's missed phone call log is not supported at this time.

Here is the documentation - http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.4/index.html